# how to write a native query in jpa for update?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I write a query to update a customer record as native query in jpa but unable to get response. it giving me some irrelevant responses

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE CUSTOMER SET NAME = :name, PHONE = :phone")
Customer updateWithNameAndPhone(@Param("name") String name, @Param("phone") String phone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the query updates the database, use the @Modifying annotation.
To indicate that the query is a native SQL query, provide the nativeQuery = true argument.
The updated customer object is not required as a return value, hence the void return type is used. You can switch the return type to Customer and adjust the function implementation if you wish to get the updated customer object.

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE CUSTOMER SET NAME = :name, PHONE = :phone WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :customerId", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void updateCustomerWithNameAndPhone(@Param("name") String name, @Param("phone") String phone, @Param("customerId") Long customerId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and guidance now I understood my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entity class CUSTOMER has NAME, PHONE & CUSTOMERID fields, you can also use Java Persistence Query Language(JPQL) below to update columns which returns Integer 1 - when one row is successfully updated & Integer 0 - when update fails and no row is updated

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.NAME = :name, c.PHONE = :phone WHERE c.CUSTOMERID = :customerId")
int updateWithNameAndPhone(@Param(value = "name") String name, @Param(value = "phone") String phone, @Param(value = "customerId") String customerId);
```

or

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.NAME = ?1, c.PHONE = ?2 WHERE c.CUSTOMERID = ?3")
int updateWithNameAndPhone(String name, String phone, String customerId);
```