# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query : Spring boot 2.7.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having below error while trying to do an `update` using `Spring Boot 2.7.5`. I've tried different approach suggested in different places but still getting the same issue. There's one issue regarding this for `spring-boot.1.2.5.RELASE` as stated in this [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3576). I wonder if the same happens with `Spring Boot 2.7.5`. Below is my code:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
        
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE PERSON SET STATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE STATUS = :status", nativeQuery = true)
    void updatePersonStatusToActive(@Param("status") String status);
}
```

I've also tried putting the `@Transactional` at the interface level right below the `@Repository`, same issue.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.updatePersonStatusToActive(Unknown Source)
    at com.people.PeopleApplication.processPerson(PeopleApplication.java:304)
    at com.people.PeopleApplication.run(PeopleApplication.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "APP_OWNER", name = "PERSON")
@Data
public class Person {   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private String personId;
    
    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String fullName;
    
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
    
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;
}
```

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591604/how-to-write-a-native-query-in-jpa-for-update/76619735#76619735)

Comment: How about when you extend `JpaRepository` instead? i.e. change `extends CrudRepository<Person, String> ` to `extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> ` . Can you also add source code of `Person` entity to the question?

Comment: Doesn't `Person` entity have an auto incremented field `private Long id`?

Comment: no, `personId` is a hash generated string value

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky because you did not add any code that generated this error message.

You can try to debug with the following:

1. Try adding the JPA repositories and transaction management with `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` to see if it makes any difference. Something like:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. There are sometimes issues with proxying with Spring interface which can lead to transaction annotations not being processed. Try to perform the update operation through a Service class instead of doing it directly in the main class or another component, an example:

```java
@Service
public class PersonService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepo personRepo;
    
    @Transactional
    public void updatePersonStatusToActive(String status) {
        personRepo.updatePersonStatusToActive(status);
    }
}
```

3. You can also add transaction logging for more visibility into the root cause `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG`

Comment: Unfortunately none of the suggestions you provided seem to work in my case, even adding the `DEBUG` level for the logs keep showing the same error information as before.

Comment: Try to see if from db side if you have privilege to update.

Comment: @DeepakNegi I do have access to update from db side